# How do I update a single value in a nested array of objects in a json document using jq?

Tags: json, edit, jq, in-place

I have a JSON document that looks like the following. Note this is a simplified example of the real JSON, which is included at bottom of question:

```
{
  "some_array": [
    {
      "k1": "A",
      "k2": "XXX"
    },
    {
      "k1": "B",
      "k2": "YYY"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to change the value of all the `k2` keys in the `some_array` array where the value of the `k1` key is "B".

Is this possible using jq ?

For reference this is the actual JSON document, which is an environment variable file for use in [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/postman) / [newman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman) tool. I am attempting this conversion using JQ because the tool does not yet support [command line overrides of specific environment variables](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/647)

Actual JSON

```
{
  "name": "Local-Stack-Env-Config",
  "values": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "key": "KC_master_host",
      "type": "text",
      "value": "http://localhost:8087"
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "key": "KC_user_guid",
      "type": "text",
      "value": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111"
    }
  ],
  "timestamp": 1502768145037,
  "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
  "_postman_exported_at": "2017-08-15T03:36:41.474Z",
  "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/5.1.3"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a slightly simpler version of [zayquan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3344695/zayquan)'s filter:

```
.some_array |= map(if .k1=="B" then .k2="changed" else . end)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another solution.

```
jq '(.some_array[] | select(.k1 == "B") | .k2) |= "new_value"'
```

Output

```
{
  "some_array": [
    {
      "k1": "A",
      "k2": "XXX"
    },
    {
      "k1": "B",
      "k2": "new_value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a viable solution:

```
cat some.json | jq '.some_array = (.some_array | map(if .k1 == "B" then . + {"k2":"changed"} else . end))'
```

produces the output:

```
  "some_array": [
    {
      "k1": "A",
      "k2": "XXX"
    },
    {
      "k1": "B",
      "k2": "changed"
    }
  ]
}
```